# Scraping hidden values from HTML with Python Using Requests and bs4 Lib

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, captcha

I am trying to scrape a Captcha code from an html source that has the code in the following format.

```
<div id="Custom"><!-- test: vdfnhu --></div>
```

The captcha code changes with each refresh. My intent is to capture the captcha and it's validation code in order to post to a form.

My code so far is:

```
import requests
import urlparse
import lxml.html
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print "Enter the URL",
url = raw_input()
r = requests.get(url)
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
div = soup.find('div' , id ='Custom')
comment = next(div.children)
test = comment.partition(':')[-1].strip()
print test
```

Comment: As a side note, what site are you scraping that uses Captcha but includes the answer in the source? That kind of completely defeats the purpose; it annoys users without even slowing down bots…

Comment: It's a lab I am working on for my cyber security masters.

Comment: [I, for one, welcome our new cyber security masters.](http://insectoverlords.org/) :)

Comment: Well I have many, many courses to go. If only I could code everything in C# life would be a lot easier. Learning python isn't hard but learning all the libraries is a beast...

Comment: Have you looked at IronPython? Python language, .NET libraries… it sounds like it might be something you'd love.

Comment: @abarnert That sounds friggin awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects) explains, BeautifulSoup has `NavigableString` and `Comment` objects, just like `Tag` objects, and they can all be children, siblings, etc. [Comments and other special strings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings) has more details.

So, you want to find the div 'Custom':

```
div = soup.find('div', id='Custom'}
```

And then you want to find the find `Comment` child:

```
comment = next(child for child in div.children if isinstance(child, bs4.Comment))
```

Although if the format is as fixed and invariable as you're presenting it, you may want to simplify that to just `next(div.children)`. On the other hand, if it's more variable, you may want to iterate over *all* `Comment` nodes, not just grab the first.

And, since a `Comment` is basically just a string (as in, it supports all `str` methods):

```
test = comment.partition(':')[-1].strip()
```

---

Putting it together:

```
>>> html = '''<html><head></head>
...           <body><div id="Custom"><!-- test: vdfnhu --></div>\n</body></html>'''
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> div = bs4.find('div', id='Custom')
>>> comment = next(div.children)
>>> test = comment.partition(':')[-1].strip()
>>> test
'vdfnhu'
```

Comment: That worked beautifully with just the next(div.children).
Thanks! 
I just couldn't wrap my mind around the comment, for some reason it was throwing me a mental loop...

Comment: @Phil: The docs for `BeautifulSoup` are very complete and well-written… but not always easily organized if you don't already know what you're searching for.

Comment: I agree, they are very well written but as you said the organization is hard to digest for someone just learning the library.